# How do I save DateTime from Flutter's DateTimePicker and write to Firebase as a Timestamp

Tags: firebase, flutter, timestamp

I am using the DatePicker as below to allow user to set Date. I want to save this selected date and time to Firebase as a Timestamp. How do I do that?

Thanks.

```
showDatePicker(
          context: context,
          initialDate: widget.isUpdating
              ? _currentExpense.createdAt.toDate()
              : _dateTime, //_currentExpense.createdAt == null,
          firstDate: DateTime(2001),
          lastDate: DateTime.now())
      .then((date) {
    _dateTime = date;
    setState(() {
      dateTimeText = _getDateString(date);
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `dateTimeObject.millisecondsSinceEpoch` to convert it to an `int` and save that to your db.

And then use `DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(msIntFromServer)` to convert it back to a DateTime object.

Or if you want even more accuracy you can do it in microseconds.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/DateTime-class.html

Comment: Thanks! So just to clarify, Timestamp is basically saved as/in milliseconds or microseconds?

Comment: Also, using your suggestion means I have to save _currentExpense.createdAt as an int in my DB and not as a Timestamp?

In my setState(), I did, _currentExpense.createdAt =
                    _dateTime.millisecondsSinceEpoch as Timestamp; but it didn't successful save to DB as it expected a Timestamp and I am sending an int as the value.

Comment: @hermie_brown I'm just saying you could save it as an int. If you already use a specified format for Timestamp in your db you should take a look at the docs from firebase or the library you're using on how to format the timestamp to that format.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I saw a post on [this google groups](https://groups.google.com/g/flutter-dev/c/EAkJ2NXC3oU/m/NOywazVpAwAJ?pli=1)
It was well in line with Er1's earlier suggestion.

For anyone seeking, here's the hack:

```
  Timestamp _dateTimeToTimestamp(DateTime dateTime) {
    return Timestamp.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(
        dateTime.millisecondsSinceEpoch);
  }

onTap: () {
  showDatePicker(
          context: context,
          initialDate: widget.isUpdating
              ? _currentExpense.updatedAt.toDate()
              : DateTime.now(),
          firstDate: DateTime(2001),
          lastDate: DateTime.now())
      .then((date) {
    _dateTime = date;
    print(_dateTime);

    setState(() {
      dateTimeText = _dateTimeToString(_dateTime);

      if (widget.isUpdating) {
        _currentExpense.updatedAt = _dateTimeToTimestamp(_dateTime);
      } else {
//this is new entry
        _currentExpense.createdAt = _dateTimeToTimestamp(_dateTime);
        _currentExpense.updatedAt = _dateTimeToTimestamp(_dateTime);
        }
     });
   });
```