# Saving the DateTime from flutter_datetime_picker to Firestore?

Tags: flutter, firebase, datetime, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp

I would like to store the `DateTime` to Firestore but I could not find any similar question. Can someone help me on this ? I'm not sure whether my Firestore implementation is correct or not but here is the current method:

[image]

Here is the code for the date picker UI :

```dart
Column(
      children: [
        ElevatedButton(
          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0)),
            elevation: 4.0,
            minimumSize: const Size(10, 10),
            maximumSize: const Size(368, 50),
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            DatePicker.showDatePicker(context,
                theme: const DatePickerTheme(
                  containerHeight: 210.0,
                ),
                showTitleActions: true,
                minTime: DateTime(2000, 1, 1),
                maxTime: DateTime(2123, 12, 31), onConfirm: (date) {
              debugPrint('confirm $date');
              _date = '${date.year} - ${date.month} - ${date.day}';
              setState(() {});
            }, currentTime: DateTime.now(), locale: LocaleType.en);
          },
          child: Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            height: 50.0,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        const Icon(
                          Icons.date_range,
                          size: 20,
                          color: Colors.blueAccent,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          " $_date",
                          style: const TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16),
                        ),
                      ],
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                const Text(
                  "  Reschedule",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.lightBlue,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 16),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 20,
        ),
        ElevatedButton(
          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0)),
            elevation: 4.0,
            minimumSize: const Size(10, 10),
            maximumSize: const Size(368, 50),
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            DatePicker.showTime12hPicker(
              context,
              theme: const DatePickerTheme(
                containerHeight: 210.0,
              ),
              showTitleActions: true,
              onConfirm: (time) {
                debugPrint('confirm $time');
                _time = '${time.hour} : ${time.minute}';
                setState(() {});
              },
              currentTime: DateTime.now(),
              locale: LocaleType.en,
            );
            setState(() {});
          },
          child: Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            height: 50.0,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        const Icon(
                          Icons.access_time,
                          size: 20,
                          color: Colors.blueAccent,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          " $_time",
                          style: const TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16),
                        ),
                      ],
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                const Text(
                  "  Reschedule",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.lightBlue,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 16),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    )
```

I'm still new to Flutter and Firestore. Can someone teach me how to store the `DateTime` to Firestore as a timestamp ?

Comment: Please share the function which is posting data to Cloud Firestore.

Comment: i've added the function that you asked but im sure if its correct or not.

Comment: There's no such function in your question.

Comment: oh thats not the function. im sorry, i'll add one and get back to you. thank you for responding to my question

Comment: See this 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64115282/how-do-i-save-datetime-from-flutters-datetimepicker-and-write-to-firebase-as-a

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to store it as a String and upload it to Firestore (Firestore doesn't have a DateTime type Object)

```
late String _date;
.
.
.
//onPressed
DatePicker.showTime12hPicker(
              context,
              theme: const DatePickerTheme(
                containerHeight: 210.0,
              ).then((newDate){
_date = DateFormat.yMd().format(newDate);},

//in the constructor change the date from DateTime to DateTime
```